# Params undefined in ng-table's getData function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am running into a problem using ng-table where the params that should be passed into my getData function is undefined. I an new to AngularJS and ng-table, so any help would be appreciated. I have verified that the REST calls in the code below work by directly invoking them, so the problem is somewhere in my angular code/configuration.

Anyhow, here is a pseudo-example of my controller. The actual code is on an intranet, so I can't paste it directly, so pardon any typos from transcription. Using ng-table 1.0.0 and angular 1.5.8:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'NgTableParams',
    function($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {
    $http.get('services/data/count').success(function(data) {
        // this works fine
        $scope.totalRows = data.rowCount;
    });
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1
        count: 20
    }, {
        total: $scope.totalRows,
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            // this line fails with params being undefined
            $http.get('/services/data/' + params.page() + '/' + params.count()) {
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                $defer.resolve(data);
            });
        }
    });
}]);
```

And here is the relevant piece of html:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        // row stuff here
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've inserted console.log statements before the getData http call, and params is printing out as undefined.

Comment: I suspect if you `console.log` your `$defer` variable, you'll see the object you were expecting `params` to hold.

Comment: Also, `$http.success` is [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice). Use `then(function(response), function(rejectionReason))` instead.

Comment: The $defer does have the values I need. I guess the question from this JS newbie is "why?" But I can move forward now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, didn't realize my comment would be confusing. Here's your answer:

The function you put in the `getData` key is assumed (by the [NgTable API](http://ng-table.com/#/loading/overview)) to take just one argument, which represents `params`. Put another way, the first argument to your `getData` function always contains `params` values, even though you named it `$defer`. And the second argument is always undefined (the API calls it with only a single argument, after all) even though you named it `params`.

If you want access to `$defer` (and it seems that you do), I think you should inject it into your controller (add `'$defer'` to your dependency array at the top, and then add `$defer` to the argument list of your controller function *in the same position*.)

It would look like this:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$defer', 'NgTableParams',
    function($scope, $http, $defer, NgTableParams) {
    $http.get('services/data/count').success(function(data) {
        $scope.totalRows = data.rowCount;
    });
    // ...
    getData: function(params) {
        $http.get('/services/data/' + params.page() + '/' + params.count()) {
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $defer.resolve(data);
        });
    }
```

Comment: was `$defer` included in the old ng-table? I also noticed that the old version used lower case `n` for `ngTableParams` unlike the current which uses upper case `NgTableParams`.

Answer (score 6):

I also ran into this issue, when I updated my ng-table. Your code should work in versions before 1.0.0 release. 1.0.0-beta.9 is the last version supporting your code.

In the [1.0.0 change notes](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/releases/tag/1.0.0) it says:

**getData signature change**

The $defer paramater supplied to your getData method has been removed. Instead your
getData method should return an array or a promise that resolves to an array.

To migrate

Previously:

```
var tp = new NgTableParams({}, { getData: getData });

function getData($defer, params){
    // snip
    $defer.resolve(yourDataArray);
}
```

Now:

```
var tp = new NgTableParams({}, { getData: getData });

function getData(params){
    // snip
    return yourDataArrayOrPromise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $defer variable (thanks Jesse Amano!) had the values I need. I am not sure why this works, but I can use it.